# android - onLocationChanged not called for distance travveled

Tags: android, location

I am using below code to periodically check location change after some distance travelled. But onLocationChanged never called.

Android Manifiest File having permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this,
                    "Provider enabled: " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this,
                    "Provider disabled: " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "onLocationChanged",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    };

locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            0,10, locationListener);
```

Comment: It wont work consistently on all phones. This feature is a mess. Instead use a service and check for location yourself.

Comment: @deniz : yes . its enabled

Comment: @Siddharth : can u pls share example?

Answer (score 0):

Check your current location id null or not. & then call onlocationchanged() if its null in your activity or service.

```
private Location location;
if (location != null) { 
            mCurrentLoc.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change like:-

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    0,10, (android.location.LocationListener) this);
```

That's it.